# Using OR in WP_Query negates the "NOT EXISTS" compare

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, meta-query

I'm attempting to filter posts by a custom field that either are equal to 'new' or have not been set yet.  I'm able to get either of those meta_queries to work on their own but when I use them in an 'OR' query, the 'NOT EXISTS" portion is ignored and the query returns every post that has ANY value set.  Here is the sample 'meta_query' that is causing the strange behavior:

```
array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key' => 'status',
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
  ),
  array(
    'key' => 'status',
    'value' => 'new',
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
);
```

Comment: There is a patch in the trac ticket linked in the comments below, you could try applying that to your current install.  As next release is 3.6, you ought to be ok.

Answer (score 7):

```
array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key' => 'status',
    'value' => '', //<--- not required but necessary in this case
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
  ),
  array(
    'key' => 'status',
    'value' => 'new',
    'compare' => '=',
  ),
);
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is a known issue: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268

Comment: as of 4.9 `'value' => '', 'compare' => '='` is doing a pretty good job.